# Running PSQL query from PHP

Tags: php, psql

I am trying to connect to PSQL and run a query from PHP but keep ending with relation does not exist.

```
$db_connection = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=matrix user=postgres password=postgres");

 php > echo $db_connection;
```

> Resource id #1

```
php > $result = pg_query($db_connection, "SELECT * FROM vmware");
```

> PHP Warning:  pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR:  relation "vmware" does
>   not exist LINE 1: SELECT * FROM vmware
>                         ^ in php shell code on line 1

```
postgres=# \dt
```

> ```
>      List of relations  Schema |  Name  | Type  |  Owner
> ```
>
> --------+--------+-------+----------  public | vmware | table | postgres (1 row)

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Weird. I can't see any error, unless the table is not called vmware (which you have already checked). Try with 'SELECT * FROM "vmware"', note the double quotes around the table name.

Comment: Same thing, which is weird. The table is not case sensitive (all lower cases) when I created. From psql command line I can run all operations on this table.

Comment: Is the table in the matrix database? Either that or the user doesn't have permission to query the table.

Comment: Is your PHP running on the same host as the database you're checking?

Comment: Yep PHP and PSQL on same box

Comment: My bad. I think I figured this out

Comment: The table was under `postgres` and I was querying `matrix` My bad. Thanks for your time guys.

Comment: go upvote some of @Skaparate's answers :D